# OpenMP implementation problems

Tags: amp-html

I tried to implement OpenCMP *(https://opencmp.net/)* on one of my AMP pages but after a short time of trying, I got stuck.

AMP documentation, section "Supported Consent Management Platforms" points to MD file *(https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-consent/cmps/opencmp.md)*. It looks like the example in that file is not finished or badly documented *(I don't know, information is fragmented)*.
There is no information on how to setup OpenCMP provider. To get rid of console error I had to dig into GitHub history *(https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/commit/1d0142daee0a35239262d191e081d0be67ec0588)*.

OpenCMP page https://opencmp.net/ only shows login page and no content or implementation info.

Is OpenCMP finished and working? Now I'm asking out of curiosity and as an alternative to Quantcast AMP implementation which is also accessible behind strange login page even when you have an account *(https://www.quantcast.com/help/guides/implementing-quantcast-measure-on-amp-project-pages/)*.

**Now I also realised that Quantcast measure is no CMP.** So I'm left with a free OpenCMP *(if it's free)*.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I was thinking that my question was clear "Is OpenCMP finished and working?". But if not, sorry about that. I will extend/break my question into bullet points.

Questions: (1) Is OpenCMP ready to use? (2) Is there some kind of documentation that I didn't found?